# iTunes does not copy some photos

Tags: itunes, photos.app

iTunes refuses to copy some photos to my iPod with the following message:

> Some of your photos, including the photo “somefile.jpg”, were not copied to the iPod “iPod” because they cannot be displayed on your iPod

Note that *loads* of photos are not copied. How can I know which photos were not copied and **why**? They can be displayed perfectly on my mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Knowledgebase article [***Issues when syncing photos to iPhone or iPod touch***](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1306) recommends deleting the [**iPod Photo Cache**](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1314) if syncing photos of a known compatible file format results in this message.